# I can connect on Postgresql Database but queries give no results

Tags: sql, postgresql, localhost, database-connection

I've a Postgresql database on my server and I would like to use it for a simple web-app on localhost. I've set the Database to allow my connections ecc.. In fact, my web-app can connect to the DB... But all the queries give no result in local. (That's funny because all the queries work great on the server.

Can you help me?

Comment: can you post the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is this:

1. Login via psql, and run the following query (note the terminating semicolon):

   SELECT version();
2. If that works, check to make sure you are terminating the queries with semicolons.
3. If that doesn't work, please copy/paste the complete output of psql (including prompts and greetings) here.

As a note, the psql prompt is very informative.  The most important character for this purpose is the second from the right.  That starts out as `=`, but changes to `-` if it is a continuation of a new line, `'` if there is an unterminated single quote, `"` if there is an unterminated double quote, etc.